# Html e-mail template - Outlook ignore width of elements

Tags: html, css

I wanted to ask, how i can force Outlook to respect widths of elements?

For example i have some piece of code inside table:

```
<tr>
    <td width="100px" style="text-align: center">
        <div style="Margin-left: 20px;Margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="divider" style="font-size: 2px;line-height: 2px;Margin-left: auto;Margin-right: auto;width: 40px!important;background-color: #ccc;Margin-bottom: 20px;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

divider class has width 40px, but in outlook, div has 100% width, why ?

Comment: in this piece of code there is not wrong

Answer (score 0):

HTML for email tends to rely purely on tables, so you're not going to be able to have `divs` within a `td`.

You'll then need to specify cell widths using both the raw `width` attribute and inline css:

```
<td width="40" style="width: 40px;">Cell content</td>
```

To be *really* safe you can go further and include a transparent 1x1 pixel image, which you can then use to force the width of cells. For example:

```
<td width="40" style="width: 40px">
  <img src="blank.gif" width="40" style="width: 40px;" />
</td>
```

I would recommend reading [Campaign Monitor's guidelines](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/guidelines/) on HTML for email.

Comment: Thanks, but <td> is also 100% width, and 40px is ignored...

<tr style="text-align: center">
        <td width="40" style="width: 40px;background-color: red;">
  <img src="blank.gif" width="40" style="width: 40px;" />sdser
</td>

        </tr>